Two problems in the pixel shader
My pixel shader is not working. I'm very bad at this so I couldn't solve this problem. Below is the pixel shader code:
cbuffer CBuf
{
    float4 face_colors[6];
};

float4 main(uint tid : SV_PrimitiveID) : SV_Target
{
    return face_colors[tid / 2];
}

And here are a couple of errors that I simply have no idea how to solve. Here are the errors:
X4583      semantic 'SV_PrimitiveID unsupported on ps_4_0_level_9_3
X4568      integer inputs unsupported on ps_4_0_level_9_3
Here I will write additional information and sorry if I didn’t tell you anything
I'm using DirectX11, the shader is made in hlsl format, both errors are sent to line 6 of the code, namely:
float4 main(uint tid : SV_PrimitiveID) : SV_Target

Please help and tell me if you need anything else. Good luck to you
I tried only two things, namely excluding the shader from the assembly (it didn’t work, obviously) and specifying in configuration > general > shader type > pixel shader (/ps).

"I'm using DirectX11" you're not.

Please check if you are using DirectX11.

SV_PrimitiveID is not supported on Direct3D 9 (which you are using since you get the error:
... unsupported on ps_4_0_level_9_3)
You need to compile for at least Direct3D 10 to use SV_PrimitiveID as stated in the Documentation

System-value semantics are new to Direct3D 10. All system-values begin with an SV_ prefix [...] These semantics have been added to Direct3D 10; they are not available in Direct3D 9.

In the Microsoft's Documentation you can see how to specify the correct target.
